# Aurelia popover checkbox checked.bind not reflecting on the view model

Tags: aurelia

We have implemented checkbox in popover. There we are using checked.bind , but in the view model its not reflecting its value on change of the checkboxes.

Sample Gist Run Provided below:

[**Gist Run**](https://gist.run/?id=6a6f019fc33ad457c6c73f294725dda8)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

#### Programmatically injected HTML needs to be compiled manually

The integration with `bootstrap` I provided to you earlier cannot do this. The bootstrap plugin assigns the `innerHTML` property of the popover and it does this outside of aurelia's rendering pipeline. The HTML is therefore not compiled by aurelia, which is why bindings (and other aurelia behaviors) will not work.

The templating framework takes care of this for you automatically as long as you are following conventions (such as custom elements). In any other case you'll need to manually work with the ViewCompiler.

In case you're interested, you can see an example with programmatically generated HTML [in this gist](https://gist.run/?id=2de948e1e5524b64ceb3c4dd64ea0c03). Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988707/composing-html-file-in-aurelia/40004730#40004730) if you want to know more about it. I do not recommend it in this scenario however.

#### Use aurelia-dialog

A tooltip (or popover) is just that: *a tip on how to use the tool*. It should not need more than some plain markup, text and styling (of course this is subjective to some degree, and some people may disagree)

For collecting user input in-between pages or screens, I'd argue a modal dialog is a better fit because of its property to "pop out" more and to de-emphasize the rest of the screen until the user either proceeds or cancels.

More importantly, by using [aurelia-dialog](https://github.com/aurelia/dialog) your bindings and behaviors will simply work because, well, it's an aurelia plugin :-)